# Lucene indexWriter commit in intervals under high concurrency load and commit immediately under low concurrency load

Tags: java, concurrency, lucene, batch-processing, lucene-nrt

I'm currently working on spring mvc based concurrent application which is creating lucene indexes for specific type of request. I previously tried to commit each document immediately by each thread but threads started to hang as a result of waiting obtain write lock under heavy concurrency load.

> java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)   at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2953)
>     - waiting to lock <0x0000000783bd7820> (a java.lang.Object)     at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:2930)

Now I'm trying to commit few documents together. I know I can commit in regular intervals by using some king of timer. **But I'm searching whether there is a way to collect bulk and commit them together under high concurrency load and commit immediately under low concurrency load.**

I tried to maintain an atomic counter variable to check how many threads are in `addDocument` code block and if there are many threads commit after all of them done adding documents.

```
    class NRTIndexManager {

    //initialization of index writer

    private AtomicInteger threadsInWritingBlock = new AtomicInteger();
    private AtomicInteger pendingCommits = new AtomicInteger();

        @Override
        public void addNewDirectory(String id, String content) {
            try {
                threadsInWritingBlock.incrementAndGet();

                indexWriter.addDocument(createDocument(id, content));

                if (threadsInWritingBlock.decrementAndGet() == 0 || pendingCommits.incrementAndGet() > PENDING_COMMIT_THRESHOLD) {
                   pendingCommits.set(0);
                   indexWriter.commit();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Unexpected error occurred. ", e);
            }
        }

    }
```

But it did not give me successful result since `addDocument` method does not take much time to execute when comparing with `commit` method.
I will be very thankful if you could guide me to find some lucene based mechanism, algorithm or any other idea to achieve this.